# Subprocess - call - Incorrect formatting for the command

Tags: python

I am reading a file & writing to another file based on delimiter '|'. I used for line in file but XML data has new lines in it which is not giving me correct results.
So i used

```
os.popen ("cut -d '|' -f2 " + tempfile + ' > ' + targetfile)
```

but while this executes my other commands in python gets execute & count check results becomes incorrect.So, I am trying to use subprocess.call as below & facing issue as command is not correct.

```
subprocess.call("cut -d '|' -f2 " + tempfile + ' > ' + targetfile)
```

can someone help to properly format this command so that it will be parsed correctly to Python?
tempfile & targetfile are parameterized values of full file paths.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.call` by default (a) expects a *list* of command line arguments, not a string, and (b) does not run using a shell, so you can't use `>` or other i/o redirection mechanisms. There are several ways of "fixing" your code:

1. Just fix it in Python.

   You're already using a language with a rich set of features for
   manipulating text. You don't need to call out to programs like
   `cut`:

   ```
   with open(tempfile) as infd, open(targetfile, "w") as outfd:
       for line in infd:
           outfd.write(line.split("|")[1])
   ```
2. Set `shell=True` on your method call so that the command is
   executed by the shell:

   ```
   subprocess.call(f"cut -d '|' -f2 {tempfile} > {targetfile}")
   ```

Comment: I tried python method like you have mentioned in many ways but the problem is it reads as a line & my XML data in 2nd column has new lines in it which because of which they are copied as a new line in target file which they shouldn't be.

Comment: I have also used below but count of records in target file doesn't match with the source file.  with open (targetfile, 'w') as mq_final_file:
       col_text = (''.join(line.partition("|")[2] for line in open(tempfile)))
       #print (col_text)
       mq_final_file.write(col_text)
       logging.info('Messages from temporary file copied to final target file.')

Comment: If you'd like to update your question with some sample data and demonstrate how the code I've suggested here does not result in the desired output I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, the data is long XML so difficult to paste here. Below is the snippet - 123456789| <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><workflowMessage><workflowMessageHeader>somewhere here there will be new line ......</workflowMessageBody></workflowMessage>~EOL~. I am getting i"Index out of range" when such record occurs. ( Records are delimited by  ~EOL~). Hopefully this helps.